# Using XS:date i want date in format YYYYMMDD

Tags: xml, xsd, w3c

Using XSD i want to only accept date of the format YYYYMMDD in my xml field ..
So how can i do that

I saw this in an example will this work ??

Comment: xs:date will be of the form YYYY-MM-DD. Why do you care what format the date is, in an xml? your app should take care of converting this to the required format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XML schema [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats) `dateTime` as ISO8601 with some exceptions and you should stick with this, otherwise you will get serious interoperability issues. If you want to send/receive date using different format, use `simpleType` with regular expression restriction and parse/format the date in your application code:

```
<xs:simpleType name="CustomDate">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{8}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

If you **really** want to mess around with built-in types (highly inadvisable), your XML framework/library might have some support for that. For instance in Java/JAXB you can apply custom transformers/formatters to any type, so that in client/server code you are still using `Date` object (not the 8-digit `String`), but it is marshalled/unmarshalled using your custom routine.

Comment: <xs:element name="BeginDate" minOccurs="1" type="xs:date"> <xs:simpleType name="CustomDate">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{8}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType name="CustomDate">             </xs:element> Is this right ?? is label CustomDate mandatory

Comment: No, you can't use both `type` on element and nested `simpleType`. Use only: <xs:element name="BeginDate"><xs:simpleType name="CustomDate">... and live with strings.

Comment: I have a legitimate case where the date format is defined by healthcare standard as YYYY[MM[DD[hh[mm[ss]]]]]. Problem is XSLT does not support that format, and modifying the document xs:date is out the question.

Comment: are you talking about hl7? How did you later parse it