# why xml schema is saying date is not valid?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a schema file and I am validating against an xml. But it is saying date of birth (date) isn't valid date. I just deleted other tags from the schema otherwise it would make it too long to read. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? I don't have much experience using xml schema before.

I am using vb.net by the way.

My xml as follow.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <EEL>
  <CANDIDATE>
  <SURNAME>JONNY</SURNAME>
  <FORENAME>WALKER</FORENAME>
  <DOB>29/12/2005</DOB>
  <SEX>M</SEX>  
  <POSTCODE>DD12DL</POSTCODE> 
  </CANDIDATE>
  </EEL>
```

in the schema,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="EEL">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="CANDIDATE">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                                               <xs:element name="DOB" type="xs:date" minOccurs ="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                                            </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLSchema requires an (almost) ISO 8601-formatted data string, which you haven't provided: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date

Answer (score 0):

The date needs to be specified in the following form "YYYY-MM-DD", by default

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254753/what-is-the-correct-format-to-use-for-date-time-in-an-xml-file-net) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039657/using-xsdate-i-want-date-in-format-yyyymmdd).

They state that to be compatible with XSD declarations, dates in Xml files have to be declared in the ISO8601 format (or something very similar to it).

Comment: More precisely, XSD-defined dates use a subset of the formats permitted by ISO 8601, for example they don't allow the abbreviated form 20130318.